# How can I display a global alert in Django admin panel?

Tags: python, django

I don't want it to show up after performing an action, I want it to show up on all pages of the Django admin panel.

Is this possible?

Comment: when you want to show alert for all CRUD operations?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a static message? I'd just override the necessary admin templates and *not* use `django.contrib.messages` as you may be tempted to - it may be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 0):

A loooong time ago I used [django-persistent-messages](https://github.com/samluescher/django-persistent-messages) for this.

Users will get a message across the top of the page which will only go away after they dismiss it by clicking on an X icon. You can use different degrees of alertness (info, warning, error, critical) so it's pretty useful.

The one caveat is that, in order to make the messages persistent, they are linked to a user account. If your website uses anonymous users you will have to think of something else (perhaps a javascript approach with cookies or one of the more modern browser storage methods)